# I did a Project in eclipse and I tried to to run it in cordova in cmd like.. Current working directory is not a cordova-based project

Tags: java, gwt

[image]

Could you please help me? I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: the first step would be posting text as **text**, not as linked image. the second step would be to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

If you download project from Internet you must first go to project directory an run command. If you don't have any project you must first create that then build it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must be missed any of below points:
1. After creating project you must make cd  so you will be inside the cordova project to do further operations.